# How to create a scrollable editor with line numbering that is always aligned with the rows in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an editor window that contains a textarea and a row numbering in a div on the left side.

I am having trouble in implementing code that will enable the numbering to move upwards with respect to row movement in textarea especially when adding a row at the bottom limit of the editor container.

The following code does exactly the opposite of my desired output in that, the row numbering is moving down when adding rows if the input in the textarea is exceeding the height of the editor division.
My expectation is to see the numbering to scroll upwards as I add more rows in my textarea.

How can I solve this problem?

```js
function updateRowNumbering(textarea) {
  const num = textarea.value.split("\n").length;
  const numbers = textarea.parentNode.querySelector(".numbers");
  numbers.innerHTML = Array(num).fill("<span></span>").join("");

  // Calculate the offset of the `.numbers` div based on the number of rows in the textarea and the scroll position.
  const offset = (num - 1) * 21

  // Update the CSS style of the `.numbers` div to move it upward and set its height.
  numbers.style.top = offset + "px";
  numbers.style.height = textarea.clientHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.editor {
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 10px;
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  line-height: 21px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #282a3a 94%, #333 6%);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.numbers {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  background: #333;
}

.numbers span {
  counter-increment: linenumber;
}

.numbers span::before {
  content: counter(linenumber);
  display: block;
  color: #506882;
}

textarea {
  line-height: 21px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: #282a3a;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 500px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
  <div class="numbers">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" onkeyup="updateRowNumbering(this)" onscroll="updateRowNumbering(this)"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a grid instead of a flexbox, and the line numbers will stay in sync with the code without you having to do any positioning in Javascript.

```js
const ta = document.querySelector('textarea')

function updateRowNumbering() {
  const num = ta.value.split("\n").length;
  const numbers = ta.parentNode.querySelector(".numbers");
  numbers.innerHTML = Array(num).fill("<span></span>").join("");
}

ta.value = `One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
`
updateRowNumbering()
```

```css
body, textarea {
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.editor {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3em auto;
  gap: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  background: rgb(40 42 58);
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.editor>* {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.numbers {
  text-align: right;
  background: #333;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.numbers span {
  counter-increment: linenumber;
}

.numbers span::before {
  content: counter(linenumber);
  display: block;
  color: #888;
}

textarea {
  line-height: 21px;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 500px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
    <div class="numbers">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <textarea wrap="off" onkeyup="updateRowNumbering()"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow! Best answer that solves my problems. Thanks Sir.

Comment: @Yogi Indeed. Done .

Comment: Updated my answer to remove `onscroll="updateRowNumbering()"`; this is not required because all the positioning is automatically handled by the grid.

Comment: If I type one very long word that gets broken into a second line, then that second line gets a new row number (typing `Threethree...three` on line #3, then the part that breaks into a new line, gets line #4, and the row showing `Four` now has #5.) Not sure if that was the intended behavior ...?

Comment: @CBroe I added `wrap="off"` to the textarea; I think that fixes the immediate issue. However, this is currently a very basic editor so I’m sure there are plenty more issues @AbednegoNasila will have to work on.

Comment: True your updated code is the best!